# Display column names with out datatype in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

`show columns from table_name;`

The above MYSQL command, displays all column names with data types in a table. I want only the column names with out other information.

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
AND table_name = 'your_table'
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f033/2)